# Working on libgdx source code, Android module build error

Tags: gradle, libgdx

I use gdx-setup to create the project.my ide is Android Studio for mac. 
I did not use gdx.jar. I add gdx source code to core module and add some custom method to SpriteBatch.

I fix build.gradle like this:

```
project(":core") {
    apply plugin: "java"

    dependencies {
       //compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"

        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-jnigen:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
    }
}
```

Desktop and ios is okay, but there is an android build error.

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/badlogic/gdx/Application$ApplicationType;
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:502)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:334)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)


:android:transformClassesWithDexForDebug FAILED
```

Comment: I only add gdx java source code to my project.

Answer (score 0):

Write this in your app.gradle

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.xxx.you.app.package"
    minSdkVersion 11
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    //add this line
    multiDexEnabled = true
}
```

the reason for this problem is conflicting jars in your project,this will surely do your work.
happy coding..

Comment: but methods in my projects no more than 64k。